# SpriteKit Block positioning

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I am trying to make a jump game in Xcode 5 with SpriteKit. 
First I want to  spawn Blocks in a random position, but reachable for the 'human' in the game that is jumping.
I got a 1. Block, that spawn at a set position. From this position, there should spawn a 2. Block, that can be + or - 80 higher or lower, and  < 80 away. Now here is the problem, I don`t know how to code it in Xcode. My code so far :

```
         SKTexture * BlockTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Block"];
    BlockTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture * BlockTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Block"];
    BlockTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKSpriteNode * Block1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:BlockTexture1];
    [Block1 setScale:1];
    Block1.position = CGPointMake( 100 , 150 );
    Block1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Block1.size];
    Block1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    Block1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    Block1.zPosition = 3;
    [self addChild:Block1];

    SKSpriteNode * Block2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:BlockTexture2];
    [Block2 setScale:1];
    Block2.position = CGPointMake( **Block1 + or - 80, Block 1 < 80** );
    Block2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Block2.size];
    Block2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    Block2.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    Block2.zPosition = 3;
    [self addChild:Block2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your started, something like this perhaps:

```
int block1x = 100;
int block1y = 150;

Block1.position = CGPointMake(block1x, block1y);

int block2x = 0;
int block2y = 0;

int r1 = arc4random() % 2; // produces random numbers between 0 and 1
if(r1 == 0)
   block2x = block1x + 80;
if(r1 == 1)
   block2x = block1x - 80;

int r2 = arc4random() % 2;
if(r2 == 0)
   block2y = block1y + 80;
if(r2 == 1)
   block2y = block1y - 80;

Block2.position = CGPointMake(block2x, block2y);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I got 4 Blocks, the same situation. how can I code it now, if only the 1. Block has a set position, and so on? Thank you again.

Comment: You can use the same principal as before. If it's all in the same method and you want to keep your code simple, just duplicate the r2 to r3 and so on.